# Do crusader and warblade stances stack?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, tome-of-battle

Since maneuvers readied from crusaders and warblades stack, can I have a crusader stance and a warblade stance active at once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No.**

You may only be in one stance at a time, unless you have the 20th level Warblade capstone feature Stance Mastery, or the Master of Nine PrC feature Dual Stance (which can only be employed a limited number of rounds per day)